# Pass DataTable from Class to Main Form

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am stupidly new to VB.. I have my Class (`dalv1`) where all my functions are stored and my Main Form.

Code is as follows:

```
Public Sub getCustomerDetails()

        Try
            Dim cust_dataTable As New DataTable()
            Dim Connection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source = C:\Users\Public\Documents\VP - A1\Database\Database.mdb"
            Dim SQL As String = ("SELECT * FROM tblCustomers")
            Dim dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Connection)
            dataAdapter.Fill(cust_dataTable)
            dataAdapter.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try

End Sub
```

I want to pass the DataTable, `cust_dataTable` to the Main Form so I can populate text boxes when the form loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn it into a function so that the table gets *returned* to the caller:

```
Public Function getCustomerDetails() As DataTable
  Dim cust_dataTable As New DataTable()
  Try
    Dim Connection As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source = C:\Users\Public\Documents\VP - A1\Database\Database.mdb"
    Dim SQL As String = ("SELECT * FROM tblCustomers")
    Dim dataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Connection)
    dataAdapter.Fill(cust_dataTable)
    dataAdapter.Dispose()        
  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("ERROR : " & ex.Message.ToString)
  End Try

  Return cust_dataTable
End Function
```

You didn't share your form's code, but here is an example of how you would call it:

```
Private da As New dalv1
Private _MyDataTable As DataTable

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As EventArgs)
  MyBase.OnLoad(e)
  _MyDataTable = da.getCustomerDetails
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I pick up the table in my main form to display the results?

Comment: @user1449737 I just updated the post.  Your question didn't indicate how your class was being used by the form, so I posted *something* that would make it operation.